# one user(admin) to all product relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel, relationship

i want to get all the list of devices with admin user. i have device_user table. But i don't have any row with admin id. I don't want to assign any device to the admin through database. I have try this .

```
    public function devices(){
        if (Gate::allows('isUser')) {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Device','device_user','user_id','device_id');
        }elseif(Gate::allows('isAdmin')){
            return Device::all();
        }
    }
```

```
$data['list_devices'] = User::where('id', $id)->with('devices')->first();
        $list = [];
        foreach ($data['list_devices']->devices as $element) {
            $list[] = $element->last_information_id;
        }
```

[image: error page]

But when i login in as other users mention in the table it works fine.
[image]

Comment: For `isUser` you're returning a relationship (which is correct), however, you're returning a collection when `isAdmin`. I would suggest moving the check to your controller and leaving the relationship as `belongsToMany`.

Comment: In your case you better to define a `scope`

Comment: And what does that means any hint